# Redirect in new Angular2 route

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

How do i use redirect to a route in the new Angular 2 router like the 'redirectTo' one in the beta version? Any 'plnkr.co' example is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**working demo** : https://plnkr.co/edit/hXJ6ZRv81kt4rvWhxoBD?p=preview

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [

      { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', terminal: true },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardCompnent}

];
```

Comment: Use pathMatch: 'full' instead of terminal: true in 3.0.0-beta2 router

Comment: what is pathMatch or terminal used for or whats the significance?

Comment: `RedirectTo` is used to redirect to specific paths.`PathMatch` is used to check path (exact path) or matching path (eg. start with `dash`) with prefix or postfix.